# Route request header for DSR (Dynamic Source Routing)

Tags: routes, protocols, tinyos

```
  typedef  nx_struct RouteRequest{

    nx_uint16_t   src ; // the node ID of RREQ originator 

    nx_uint16_t   desn ;  // the node ID of desired destination

    nx_uint16_t   reqid;  // unique id to recognize duplicate request

   nx_uint16_t  route_record;  // append node address in the route record

    nx_uint8_t  numhops;  // hop count 
 } RouteRequest;
```

My question is while route request (src,desn,reqid) will be the same till it reaches the target node. In route record each note has to append its address(Node_id) in it. then there will be change of bytes in the route record, right??
Please help me in this regard ..

Thanks, Prem

Answer (score 0):

The route record will be extended at each hop, appending bytes at each hop. This list of bytes can be used by each packet along the way to learn about its predecessors.